# Set ticks 10 times between every major 10^x tick on a axis with a logarithmic scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

What I want:
[image: Goal]

What I got:
[image: Reality]

I want to add minor ticks on a axis with a logarithmic scale (`ax.set_xscale("symlog")`), e.g. between 10^1 (=10) and 10^2 (=100) I want ticks at 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, and 90; between 10^2 (=100) and 10^3 (=1000) I want ticks at 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, and 900.

Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(some_data)
ax.plot(some_other_data)
ax.set_xscale("symlog")
```

I think I need something like

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(1e05))
```

but without the fixed value "1e05".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a minimal example reproducing what you get so we can work on it, and build our answer from what you already have !

Comment: Do you need `symlog` for a specific reason?

Comment: @Scotty1- This is it! When I used just ```log``` before, the whole axis looked untidy and ugly, but I must have changed something in the code since then as now when I change from ```symlog``` to just ```log``` the axis looks just as i wanted it to look like! Thank you so much. As I'm new to Stack Overflow: Should I just delete this (silly) question? Or do you want to add your comment as an answer and I will approve it, so when somebody else has got the same question they will find an answer fast?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes strange things happen. :) You can leave the question as it is. I added an answer considering symlog.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to directly insert your images into the question instead of adding links to your images.

Comment: @KimTang You need 10 reputation to do this (I've got them through this question :) ) [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question)

Comment: @sterafix Oh sorry, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for informing me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you definetely want to use `symlog` (which is only required for negative values!), then you need to set the tick locator accordingly:

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.LogLocator(base=10, subs='all'))
```

Otherwise I recommend using `ax.set_xscale("log")`. This should provide the correct minor ticks by default.